# Uploading file from Android with PHP Internal Error

Tags: php, android, file-upload, internal-server-error

I'm trying to upload a picture from an Android device to a server via php, but I'm having some problems. When the file goes to upload, it appears that the file is reaching the server (I can see the tmp files that are several hundred kb), but the file isn't getting saved to the directory as a .jpg file like I want. The server response I'm getting is 500 - Internal Error.

I put a basic html form on the server so that I can test the php upload file from a browser, and it uploaded a picture just fine using my pc and the browser on my phone. So it's just my app its not working on. Is it a problem with the configuration of the server/php or is it in the way it's uploading? Here is the code:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
String pathToOurFile = listOfFiles.getFirst().toString();
String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary =  "*****";
int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
byte[] buffer;
int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

try {
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

                URL url = new URL(serverAddress);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Allow Inputs & Outputs
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setUseCaches(false);

                // Enable POST method
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

                outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // Read file
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                Log.v("UPLOAD*********", "Server Code: " + serverResponseCode);
                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                    successfulUploads++;
                    listOfFiles.removeFirst();
                } else {
                    numberOfTries++;
                }

                fileInputStream.close();
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                numberOfTries++;
            }
```

And here is the php file:

```
<?php 
 $target = "uploads/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 {
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']). " has been uploaded";
 } 
 else {
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: It would be more insightful if you post the log information of Apache or whatever web server you are using. Additionally, you might identify the error by printing out the `$_FILES['filename']['error']` or even printing the entire `$_FILES` array using `print_r($_FILES)`.

Comment: I don't know anything about php and very little about the server side of stuff. I installed IIS on a windows 7 machine and then installed PHP.  How would I go about getting more info about the error/log info? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Digging out this topic, I have the same error and can't find any working answer, did you remember how you solved this ? Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem... did you find out answer ? My question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493855/file-upload-through-android-gives-503-but-works-fine-in-rest-client